# Why is my container not running?"Running": false

Tags: docker

When I run

```
docker container create -i -t --name mycontainer alpine
a95321be84cc14458b3283d97f21d26dd093139bf5a0f67c31a0ab4adbe3fd11
```

Let's inspect the container

```
"Id": "a95321be84cc14458b3283d97f21d26dd093139bf5a0f67c31a0ab4adbe3fd11",
"Created": "2022-08-25T09:19:11.576071965Z",
"Path": "/bin/sh",
"Args": [],
"State": {
    "Status": "created",
    "Running": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
    "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

I am on Ubuntu,version

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:03 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't *run* the container, you just *[created](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/)* it. It is ready to run, but not yet running.

`docker container start mycontainer` will *run* the container you created. It should then show up in the container list - `docker container list`.

Comment: After Docker run I do not have container again. Docker run alpine.